# App Engine - Mobile Safari - AJAX - Page load time takes around 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, mobile-safari

I have come across a strange bug that I just can't figure out.

The page does not execute the ajax json call for 30 seconds.

Here is how I recreate the bug:

- Phone: iPhone 6 with iOS 9.0.1
- Safari: Cleared history and website
  data in safari settings
- Wifi: Turn off cellular data and leave wi-fi
  only
- Page: Go to page http://www.bazmo.com/best/staplers

It does work properly when using cellular data and even on wifi using Web Inspector.

Here are the Google App Engine logs:

```js
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/json/' + currentUrlPath,
        success: function (dataSource) {
            // Populate item list
            data = dataSource;
            alert("works");
            // Apply CategoryViewModel binding
            $(function () {
                ko.applyBindings(new CategoryViewModel(),
                        document.getElementById("outer_content"));
            });
        }
```

Thanks in advance!
Kris

Comment: use that browsers debugging/profiling tools to find out where that wait is spent

Comment: I did. It ended up being that the JS files itself is not firing/loading when it is not cached. For some reason it takes 30 seconds for the JS files to fire/load. Not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: What you pasted in your question isn't app engine logs, it's a code snippet.

Comment: As well, what are the JS files which take long to load, how are they being served, and what information can you gather from logs on your server?

Comment: Wait, you say JS files, and then you say JSON. Where does the latency occur, when serving the JSON file? Or a JS file?